# Comparison between fractional type

Tags: haskell, floating-point, equality

```
ghci> 4 == 3.9999999999999999
True

ghci> 10.2^2 == 104.04
False
```

Why the 2nd expression returns False?

Comment: lookup numeric precision and respresentation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Floating point values do not have a sensible notion of equality. Arguably, it is an error in Haskell that the expression even type checks. The issue is common to all languages that use floating point representations.

Some references on floating point:

- **[Comparing floating point numbers](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm)**

Consider using [the `Rational` type in Haskell](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.1.0/doc/html/Data-Ratio.html#t:Rational), if you need correct math here, but note that it supports a smaller range of operations, and less hardware support.

```
Prelude> 4 == (3.9999999999999 :: Rational)
False
Prelude> 10.2^2 == (104.04 :: Rational)
True
```

Comment: Note that this works because floating point literals are overloaded, just like integer literals, e.g. `10.2` means `fromRational (102 % 10)`.

Comment: Equality of floating point numbers lets you, e.g., memoize functions or check if a file has changed on systems which give timestamps as floats.  Floating point numbers are exact, but operations on them (especially radix conversions) are inexact.

Comment: @Dietrich Epp: I tend to think of float equality as similar to pointer equality of values on the heap--it tells you if things are exactly identical, not if they're distinct but equivalent in a meaningful way.

Comment: @camccann: I think of it exactly the same way.

Comment: Floating point has a perfectly sensible notion of equality.  It's your expectations of the values being compared that are incorrect.

Comment: @Stephen - if by "perfectly sensible" you mean "`x == x` can be false, and `x == y` can depend on whether or not `x` and/or `y` were roundtripped through memory since the time they were computed"...

Comment: @mokus: Yes, it's perfectly sensible.  It follows a clear, easily understandable set of rules.  If a programmer is going to use floating-point types, it's her responsibility to learn and understand those rules.  The excess-precision issue is an implementation detail of specific floating-point hardware, not a property of floating-point itself.

Comment: Those rules are different enough to the classical notion of structural equality, to the point that structural equality operators are misleading, which is my point.

Comment: @Stephen - I agree that in that sense it is perfectly sensible, but I also tend to agree with @Don and others that it is not really a "notion of equality", at least not a mathematical one.  The first case (`x == x` being false) doesn't rely on excess precision, it's in the IEEE spec.  NaN == NaN is false, even for identical NaNs. That makes it not an equality relation, by definition.  But then, "equality" has always been treated more pragmatically in programming than in mathematics.  After all, equality of real numbers isn't actually even decidable (constructively, anyway) in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

- [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Stack Overflow should automatically link you to this whenever it detects a decimal point in a question :)

Comment: I don't think this question is actually about floating point arithmetic though. I think they're aware of those issues, but were wondering why 4 == 3.9999... but 104.04 != 104.03999..., and the answer is just because GHCI rounds 3.999... if there are enough 9s.

Comment: @hammar: only if we can also have SO automatically deduct 100 rep everytime someone posts an "answer" consisting solely of this link.

Comment: @Stephen: Would you care to elaborate? This linked article pretty-much *is* the canonical answer to these type of questions. Any elaboration added by me would just be unnecessary repetition of what's in the article.

Comment: @LukeH: It's like answering a question about an implementation detail of red-black trees with a link to CLRS.  The answer is probably in there somewhere, but that doesn't make it useful to the questioner, except in the broad "you should really read this" sense.

Comment: @Stephen: We'll have to agree to disagree. The "What Every Computer Scientist..." article answers the OP's question correctly. (And if the text of CLRS was freely available online, and if the relevant section of it answered a particular question, then I'd see nothing wrong with posting a link to that section as an answer. If a clear, canonical answer already exists, how does paraphrasing it badly here improve the overall SNR?)

Answer (score 4):

#### When equality tests do and do not work on floating point numbers

You should learn about representation of floating point numbers in the computer memory. See other answers for helpful links. In fact, strict comparison `(==)` almost never works reliably against them.

Most of the real numbers cannot be represented with machine floating point precisely. Only few of them (like `i/2^n`, where `i` and `n` are integers) are represented precisely. The others are not. This implies, that in general the equality test has unpredictable result on floating point numbers, and the only situation where you can use it is when you known a priory that the numbers are in the above mentioned form. This may work well when planning and writing tests.

#### Three approaches

The workaround is to use *less than* or *greater than* tests on floating point numbers most of the time (or use rational numbers). When you still want to compare two floating point numbers (e.g. in tests), you can define the accuracy of comparison.

```
ghci> let eq tol a b = tol > abs (a-b)
ghci> eq 1e-6 4 3.9999999999999999
True
ghci> eq 1e-6 (10.2^2) 104.04
True
```

You may also consider using `(~==)` approximate comparison from [ieee754](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/ieee754/0.7.2/doc/html/Data-AEq.html) package. But accuracy of the results in most of the real-life calculations is well below the accuracy of the maching floating point types, so it still makes sense to allow some error.

#### The answer

> Why the 2nd expression returns False?

104.04 should be 2601/25, not a number in the form `i/2^n`, so it cannot be represented precisely with floating point numbers (GHCi defaults to `Double`, probably). So it happens that on your platform 10.2^2 is not equal 104.04. On another platform they could have happened to be equal.

However, if you used rational numbers, they would be equal:

```
ghci> (102%10)^2 == (10404%100)
True
```

Comment: I don't agree that you should compare approximately in general.  Any time you compare floating point numbers for equality you should pause and think about what you are doing.  It's almost always wrong to compare floating point numbers for equality.  Using approximate equality just sweeps the problem under the rug.  For instance, approximate equality is not an equivalence relation, i.e., `a ~== b && b ~== c` does not imply `a ~== c` as one would expect.

Comment: Only powers of 2 are represented precisely with floating point numbers (0.5, 0.25, ...). In the rest of the situations, where floating point numbers are used, it is usually possible to compare them only approximately, either up to the precision of the type, or to the precision of the application. More often than not, the application (input data precision, methods used, etc.) dictates worse precision than the precision of type. Hence, `eq`.

Comment: I just repeat what I said.  If you need to compare floating point numbers for equality, think long and hard. :)

Comment: @augustuss I repeat what I've written in the answer, `(<)` or `(>)` is the usual way to go :-) P.S. Better if the algorithm itself is formulated without the need to compare floats, that's for sure.

Comment: Strict equality **always works reliably** the problem is with people's incorrect expectations of the values being compared, not with the comparison itself.

Comment: @Stephen Puns aside. As a computer operation it works reliably, but it cannot be relied upon as an equality test for real numbers, because 1) the set of floating numbers is not the same as the set of real numbers (⇒ some real numbers may have more than one approximate representation in the set of floating point numbers); 2) computer operation of floating point equality does not correspond to real number equality, but to accidental representation equality; 3) most real-valued computations have limited accuracy anyway, so range checks should be used most of the time.

Comment: @jetxee: no.  1) Except for zero, each real number rounds to a unique binary floating point representation determined by the rounding mode, and the two representations of zero compare equal.  2) (ignoring zeros and NaNs, which are not at issue here) floating-point equality is *precisely* the same as real number equality.  Comparisons are one of the only things that *aren't* dramatically different in floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: @Stephen Canon: Most of applications are limited by (3), and for that reason alone equality is to avoid, even if the floating point numbers were precise representation. Regarding (1) (FPNs not being *Q* nor *R*): OK, I accept that rounding convention mitigates non-unique representation; but the problem is how you obtain the same number; for the same reason, FPNs not being *Q* nor *R*, any non-trivial calculation accumulates representation errors, `(sqrt 2.0)^2 /= 2.0`, `(1 + 1e-16) - 1 /= 1e-16`. And (3): It is still only _representation_ equality: `(1 + 1e-17) == (1 + 2e-17 :: Double)`.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply a case of rounding. If you just input 3.9999999999999999 into GHCI, you'll see it gets rounded to 4.0, which is clearly equal to 4. 10.2^2 evaluates to 104.03999999999999, which does not get rounded and is not equal to 104.04. The reason it evaluates incorrectly, which you may already know, is because of [floating-point arithmetic problems](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: 10.2^2 does *not* evaluate to 104.03999999999999; the latter is an approximation using decimal notation.  To find out the exact answer `toRational (10.2^2) = 3660582072122081 % 35184372088832`, whereas `toRational 104.04 = 7321164144244163 % 70368744177664`.  Two entirely different rational numbers, that differ by `(-1) % 70368744177664`.

Comment: @augustss In fact, what `10.2^2` evaluates to depends on its type (context). For example, `(10.2^2) :: Rational` evaluates to `2601 % 25`, which is the exact value. The same applies also to `(104.04 :: Rational)`.

Comment: augustss: Whether it evaluates to `104.03999999999999` or `3660582072122081 / 35184372088832` is a matter of perspective.  They are two different representations of the same IEEE 64-bit floating point number, and so I would contend that both are equally correct in that sense.  The second is correct in the sense of being the rational number it represents, but arguably it is the use of that perspective which leads to the problems people have when using floating point numbers in the first place.  Floating point numbers are not reals or even rationals; not even a subset of them.

Comment: (continuing)  Of course, the second has the advantage that it is correct in both contexts :)